# Why does -name work but I cannot use -regex in Mac terminal?

Tags: regex, bash, macos, file, find

On my Mac running Yosemite I have a directory of files on my Desktop:

```
29_foo10.bar
29_foo2.bar
29_foo20.bar
29_foo3.bar
```

I want to target the files with a single digit after `foo`.  When I use `find -name` I can target the selection of files with:

```
USERNAME=darthvader
DIRECTORY="/Users/$USERNAME/desktop/test"
for theProblem in $(find $DIRECTORY -type f -name '29_foo[0-9].bar'); do
    cd $DIRECTORY
    echo $theProblem
done
```

and I'm returned the two files in the terminal (`29_foo2.bar` & `29_foo3.bar`) but when I try using `-regex` it returns nothing, code:

```
for theProblem in $(find $DIRECTORY -type f -regex '29_foo[0-9].bar'); do
    cd $DIRECTORY
    echo $theProblem
done
```

I did some research and found [OS X Find in bash with regex digits \d not producing expected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843828/os-x-find-in-bash-with-regex-digits-d-not-producing-expected-results)

so I modified my code to:

```
for theProblem in $(find -E $DIRECTORY -iregex '29_foo[0-9].bar'); do
```

and I'm returned:

> No such file or directory

so I tried:

```
for theProblem in $(find -E $DIRECTORY -type f -regex '29_foo[0-9].bar'); do
```

but I still get:

> No such file or directory

So I did some further research and found [bash: recursively find all files that match a certain pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207896/bash-recursively-find-all-files-that-match-a-certain-pattern) and tested:

```
for theProblem in $(find $DIRECTORY -regex '29_foo[0-9].bar'); do
```

and I'm returned:

> No such file or directory

Further down the rabbit hole I found [How to use regex in file find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249779/how-to-use-regex-in-file-find) so I tried:

```
for theProblem in $(find $DIRECTORY -regextype posix-extended -regex '29_foo[0-9].bar'); do
```

and terminal tells me:

> find: -regextype: unknown primary or operator

Why in Yosemite am I not able to target the files with `-regex`?  When I do `man regex` I am returned the manual, my bash version is 3.2.57.  So why does `-name` work when `-regex` will not?

Comment: Note some of the solutions you found do work on [GNU find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find), while your [OSX find](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) misses some of the options like `-regextype`.

Comment: @fedorqui are you aware of any documentation that notes what is missing between GNU and OSX?

Comment: Mmm no :/ And I wish there was one.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the [POSIX specification for `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html). When trying to write portable code, it's more useful to be aware of what features are *extensions* to your particular version, rather than to think of what is *missing* from another version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this regex in `find`:

```
find "$DIRECTORY" -type f -regex '.*/29_foo[0-9]\.bar$'
```

Changes are:

- `.*/` is required at start because there will be either a `DOT` or some directory path before each filename.
- Added anchor `$` in the end to avoid matching `29_foo3.barn` if at all this filename is also there.
- DOT needs to be escaped in `-regex` otherwise it will match any character.
- Above `find` command will work on OSX-`find` as well on gnu-`find`.

Comment: excellent and it works.  To clarify, since I did see you edited but is it standard practice to always use `.*/` when calling on `-regex` and the DOT will always need to be escaped and it's not optional?

Comment: DOT should be escaped as a good practice in regex otherwise it will also match a filename `29_foo2_bar`. `.*/` before your regex is definitely required since `-regex` is matching against full path of file starting from base path `"$DIRECTORY"`.